# SCDL Troubleshooting

Tags: python

I am trying to run SCDL to scrape SoundCloud, however I am getting the following error message:

```
developer@developer /u/d/m/downloads> scdl
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 
(1.23) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/scdl", line 5, in <module>
from scdl.scdl import main
File "/Users/developer/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/scdl/scdl.py", line 73, in 
<module>
from scdl import __version__, CLIENT_ID, ALT_CLIENT_ID
ImportError: cannot import name __version__
```

Comment: How did you install SCDL? You seem to be using Python 2 which was officially discontinued.

Comment: I used Python 3 I believe.

Comment: I don't believe.

Comment: What did you do, what tutorial did you follow, etc.. to end up having the command not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pacholik seems to be right. The error message clearly says you're using python2.7's `requests` library, and that's probably incompatble with scdl. Try installing it into Python 3.

Comment: Do you know what command I would use to do that?

Comment: Probably just follow the [SCDL install instructions](https://github.com/flyingrub/scdl#installation) which have you use `pip3`: that should be enough to get it into the Python3 libraries.

Comment: I actually used pip3 to install it.